# invalid context_id error in LootLocker with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, storage

I'm trying to generate user content in Unity with LootLocker. Authentication works fine, but I'm not able to create an asset no matter what. I tried versions 2.1.1 and 1.2.7. This is the code I'm using:

```cs
public class LootLockerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        GuestLogin();
    }

    public void TakeScreenshot(string levelName)
    {
        string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Assets/Screenshots/";
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Path.Combine(filePath, levelName + "-screenshot.png"));
    }

    IEnumerator WaitScreenshot(string levelName)
    {
        TakeScreenshot(levelName);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    public void SaveLevelCloud(string inputName)
    {
        string name = "New Asset Candidate";
        LootLockerSDKManager.CreatingAnAssetCandidate(name, (response) =>
        {
            if (response.success)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Sucess creating asset candidate");
                Debug.LogWarning(response.text);
                //UploadLevelData(response.asset_candidate_id, inputName);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Error creating asset candidate");
                Debug.LogWarning(response.text);
            }
        });
    }

    
    public void GuestLogin()
    {
        TextMeshProUGUI logStatus = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("LogStatusText").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        LootLockerSDKManager.StartGuestSession((response) =>
        {
            if (!response.success)
            {
                SaveLevelCloud("test");
                return;
            }

         
        });
    }
}
```

And the output it generates:
[image: Output]

Thanks in advance.